# how to impove game-server performance with mutil-core cpu

Tags: javascript, c, concurrency, network-programming, node.js

how to impove game-server performance with mutil-core cpu 
My point:

1. one busy process make one core busy, if only one busy process, very bad.
2. multi-process process **and** listen on diffrent port imporved concurrency connections
3. multi-process can't share the memory data directly. they need communicate.
4. they can communicate in socket, fp socket, and redis
5. seperate game-server into diffrent functions, each function a standalone process, some function can be parrallel processes.

if my point is correct, my question is:

*what's the best way to communicate between processes, and keep the data synchronized, the best means fast and simple.*

I am using nodejs, but I think it's the same with c for this topic.

Edit:

*Sharding or seperate by functions , which is better*

Comment: #1 isn't bad, it allows you to run multiple game-servers on one machine.  Multi-threading means you are now very restricted on running multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

There are many discussions about that available on internet so I am just joining the links instead of repeating what they say:

- [Use Threads Correctly = Isolation + Asynchronous Messages](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=SARKGLEK332IHQE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=215900465)
- [Use Thread Pools Correctly: Keep Tasks Short and Nonblocking](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=SARKGLEK332IHQE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=216500409)
- [Break Up and Interleave Work to Keep Threads Responsive](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=SARKGLEK332IHQE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=217801299)
- [Sharing Is the Root of All Contention](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=SARKGLEK332IHQE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=214100002)
- [Design for Manycore Systems](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=SARKGLEK332IHQE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=219200099)

These links show the best practices to create a safe and well designed parallel solution.

I would advice to create a pool of threads to handle the connections. One thread per connection. That's the common "pattern" for servers.

Answer (score 0):

One method for node.js is to use [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), which allows you to communicate between threads, processes, and servers with the same simple BSD sockets compatible API.

Here's the node.js binding to try:

https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node